# FMDB not show anything - swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fmdb

I would like to use my local database.
To do this I'm using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

1.I added `pod 'FMDB'` to `pod file` then `pod install`

2.I dragged my database to my project (`kashanmapDB_upgrade_3-4.db`).

[image]

3.I created a class called `DatabaseManager.swift`

my class:

```
import Foundation
import FMDB
class DatabaseManager {

    private let dbFileName = "kashanmapDB_upgrade_3-4.db"
    private var database:FMDatabase!

    init() {
        openDatabase()
    }

    func openDatabase() {

        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
        let dbPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: paths).appendingPathComponent(dbFileName)
        let str_path = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent(dbFileName).path
        let database = FMDatabase(path: str_path)

        /* Open database read-only. */
        if (!(database?.open(withFlags: 1))!) {
            print("Could not open database at \(dbPath).")
        } else {
            print("opened database")
            self.database = database;
        }
    }

    func closeDatabase() {
        if (database != nil) {
            database.close()
        }
    }

    func query(queryString:String) {
        if let db = database, let q = db.executeQuery(queryString, withArgumentsIn: nil) {
            while q.next() {
                let data = q.string(forColumn: "id")
                // Do whatever here with fetched data, usually add it to an array and return that array
                print("data a a  \(data)")
            }
        }
    }


}
```

4. In my controller I created a variable to my class and invoke my functions :

   ```
     let db = DatabaseManager()

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createPageViewController()
    setupPageControl()

     db.openDatabase()
     db.query(queryString: "select * from Tags")

   }
   ```

but my console not show anything. where is my problem?

Comment: Is the database opened successfully?

Comment: not printed anything like `Could not open database at` or `opened database`

Comment: first copy your database to document directory and then open

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

1. first you have uninstall your old app.
2. Delete your old "kashanmapDB_upgrade_3-4.db" file from Xcode as well as finder -> Project directory.
3. Copy/add again "kashanmapDB_upgrade_3-4.db" file by ensure that **copy selected items checked**

   ```
                        OR
   ```
4. In Xcode-> Go to Application Project -> Linked Framework and lib -> Click on **"+"** button to add "kashanmapDB_upgrade_3-4.db" file t o your project
5. In Xcode Project - Product -> Clean project and 
   then -> Build -> Run.

That's it done...!!!